# JSON eval() data inside a JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, eval

I am working with JSON and ajax. I am trying to post a value using AJAX. below is my issue:

My post value:

JSON:

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }]
}
```

I am posting JQuery eval() method it converts the JSON object as following:

```
&firstName=john&lastName=Deo
```

My problem comes when I try to post a JSON in side a JSON:

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": {
            "test1": "10",
            "test2": "12"
        }
    }]
}
```

When I use eval() method the above JSON object as follows:

```
&firstName=John&lastName=&test1=10&test2=12
```

My JQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: applicationURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: eval("(" + queryString + ")"),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: (60 * 10000),
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (objAJAXRequest, strError) {
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to get the values of lastName as JSON object as above? Because eval() method coverts the lastName value also as & separate?

Comment: Cant you just post the JSON object, or stringified object to the Call, and then the PHP do a decode?  Thats what i would do.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Where and why are you using `eval()` here?  What does "posting JQuery eval() method" mean?

Comment: To get a common string structure..

Comment: @TomPHP: Can you show us your actual code?  I can't understand why `eval()` would be used here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Kindly check my Ajax code.. Updated...

Comment: @TomPHP: What is `queryString`?  Why can't you just do `data: queryString`?  I don't see why you need `eval()` here, nor how your objects are "converted".  You are probably over-complicating this problem.  Just take the JavaScript object, and set it as `data`.  jQuery will convert it to key/value pairs that PHP can read.

Comment: Qerystring equals the JSON {
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": {
            "test1": "10",
            "test2": "12"
        }
    }]
}

Comment: @TomPHP: Then just do `JSON.parse(queryString)`.  Don't use `eval()`.  I don't see how you are getting the string `&firstName=John&lastName=&test1=10&test2=12`.

Comment: *"My problem comes when I try to post a JSON in side a JSON:"* that isn't json inside json.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", data: {mydata: JSON_OBJ});
```

and then in PHP:

$obj = json_decode($_POST["mydata"]);

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php